# How to load different banner picture on the same header.php?

Tags: jquery, html, css, header, banner

I am creating a WP theme. The structure and the design are pretty complex, so I need to find a pattern how to program everything.

I have different type of pages, which are grouped in sections. All pages in the website has the same navigation, but all pages from one section have specific banner. In other words, I have either create 5 different header.php files (which contains the same navigation bar and different banner on the back), or create one header.php and load specific banner, based on the section.

I assume it is possible, but cannot find more information.
Any idea?

Thanks

**EDIT**

page.php:

```
if(is_page(14)) {
$class_name='headerNew';
get_header();
}
```

style.css:

```
.headerNew{
 background-image: url('img/explorebg.png')
  }

 .headerSupport{
    background-image: url('img/supportbg.png');
  }
```

header.php:

```
  <div class="<?php echo($class_name);?>">
```

It seemts okay, but nothing displays.

Comment: IMO you should have only one header.php and do the main logic there, it will be more clean way. Because, if you wanna change something (or making many changes) in **future**, with that method you could make only one change instead of 5. It saves you time

Comment: Also, it was better to put example of your code here to be more specific. If those specific banners are very complex (**or very different by structure**), then maybe doing it the other way would be better. However, without looking at code it's hard to understand your situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Max Water
Since I did not started to work on that, there is not much code to show. I have a simple picture, showing the main idea. 
We have 4 pages and 2 sections. The white area is a navigation bar. It stays always the same. @ pages have blue banner and 2 pages have red banner. It is just a picture. So in header.php, for sure I will have nvigation bar and banner picture. The question is, How to change the picture, based on the page?

[See the picture for more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCkrt.png)

Comment: You're doing frontend part only? If you could change php code (backend part), you could get it working with variables of current page, for example. If your project is on php, the best way of doing what you want is to create only one page and write the conditions (if url name or page name is `x` then use banner `x`, if `y` then use banner `y` etc.)

Comment: Yep :) Or instead of using url, simply put a variable in top of that pages that are including `header.php`. That variable will vary from page `x` to page `y` (in x.php that variable will be 1, in y.php it will be 2). Then in `header.php`: `if (variable==1){..use banner x..}else{..use banner y..}`.

Comment: The problem is that in my case I define the picture as a background of div container. This means that the picture should change in the style.css as  background-image: url('img');. Is there a way to make if conditions in there and check the pages in the css file?

Comment: In css you could create one class for each banner. `.banner-a` and `banner-b` (and if they have something in common, create one more class `.banner-common`, for example. There you can put common features). In each class you set `background-image` as you want. Then you should determine in pages which to use. This is the same thing as I described in prev comment: `if (var==1) {$class_name='banner-a';}else{$class_name='banner-b';}`. Then, to that div you set `<div class="<?php echo($class_name);?>"></div>`, for example. Php will know which page u use by variable `var`.

Comment: See also : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25248526/7321917)
Here is what I'm talking about :)

Comment: Yes, if you're getting result - it is working. Seems to be good. You can use array also, instead of `if`. Simple example:

`$arr = ['banner-a','banner-b','banner-c'];

$class_name = $arr($page_id);
get_header();
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159899/discussion-between-max-water-and-vanina-yordanova).